# Nav Bar in Wordpress will not Display: Block

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

[image: What the site is supposed to look like]
The above picture is what my nav bar more or less is supposed to look like. I'm coding my wordpress site from scratch and my nav bar with a header class="site-header" will not display:block or have its text-decoration removed. What's strange is that

```
.site-header nav ul li {
margin-right: 5px;
}
```

works. The boxes just don't show up for some reason.

Help would be much appreciated : )

```css
/* 
Theme Name: Yonsei Fencing
Author: Yonsei Student
Version: 1.0
*/

body {
 font-family: 'Malgun Gothic','맑은고딕', Arial, 돋움, Dotum, 굴림, Gulim, AppleGothic, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #333;
}

a:link
a:visited {
 color: #006ec3;
}

p {
 line-height: 1.65em;
}

/* General Layout */
div.container {
 max-width: 920px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
}

article.post {
 border-bottom: 2px dotted #999;
}

article.post:last-of-type {
 border-bottom: none;
}

/* Header */
.site-header {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #999
}

/* Footer */
.site-footer {
 margin-top: 30px;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #999
}

/* Navigation Menus */
.site-nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.site-nav ul:before, .site-nav ul:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.site-nav ul:after { clear: both; }
.site-nav ul { *zoom: 1; }

.site-nav ul li {
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
}

/* Site Header Menu */
.site-header nav ul li {
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.site-header nav ul li a:link,
.site-header nav ul li a:visited, {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 18px;
 border: 1px solid #BBB;
 border-bottom: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}


.site-header nav ul li a:hover {
 background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!--footer.php-->
    <footer class="site-footer">
 
  <nav class="site-nav">
    <?php

    $args = array(
     'theme_location' => 'footer'
    );

    ?>

    <?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
  </nav>

  <p><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - &copy; <?php echo date('Y');?></p>
 
 </footer>

</div><!--/container-->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>

<!--functions.php-->
<?php

function learningWordPress_resources() {

 wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'learningWordPress_resources');

// Navigation Menus
register_nav_menus(array(
 'primary' => __('Primary Menu'),
 'footer' => __('Footer Menu'),
));

<!--header.php-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
 <head>
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
 </head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

 <div class="container">

  <!--site-header-->
  <header class="site-header">
   <h1><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a> </h1>
   <h5><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h5>

   <nav class="site-nav">
    <?php

    $args = array(
     'theme_location' => 'primary'
    );

    ?>

    <?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
   </nav>

  </header><!--/site-header-->
 

<!--index.php-->
      <?php

get_header();

if (have_posts()) : 
 while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

 <article class="post">
 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
 <?php the_content(); ?>
 </article>
 
 <?php endwhile;

 else: 
  echo '<p>No content found</p>';

 endif;

get_footer();

?>
```

[image: My wordpress site]}

Comment: Your `li` elements are `block`s but maybe the `float` is making them in one line? I am not entirely sure what you mean. As for `text-decoration` I believe you need to apply that to the anchor tags `.site-header nav ul li a`.

Comment: Hey Aziz, I uploaded a photo better illustrating what I'm trying to achieve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a minor syntax error, causing your styles to not be applied:

> ```
> .site-header nav ul li a:link,
> .site-header nav ul li a:visited, {
> ```

The extra comma `,` at the end expects an additional selector, but was met with a `{`. Simply remove the extra comma. That should solve your problems.

Working demo:

```css
/* 
Theme Name: Yonsei Fencing
Author: Yonsei Student
Version: 1.0
*/

body {
  font-family: 'Malgun Gothic', '맑은고딕', Arial, 돋움, Dotum, 굴림, Gulim, AppleGothic, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #333;
}

a:link a:visited {
  color: #006ec3;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.65em;
}

/* General Layout */

div.container {
  max-width: 920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

/* Header */

.site-header {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #999
}

/* Navigation Menus */

.site-nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.site-nav ul:before,
.site-nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.site-nav ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

.site-nav ul {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.site-nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

/* Site Header Menu */

.site-header nav ul li {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.site-header nav ul li a:link,
.site-header nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  border-bottom: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.site-header nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--site-header-->
  <header class="site-header">
    <h1><a href="#">Blog Name</a></h1>
    <h5>Blog Desc</h5>
    <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```